# Define an array with multiple type-objects in it

Tags: typescript

I defined some Animals with 3 properties in common, the rest is different in every sub-type

```
type Animal = {
    id: string
    type: AnimalTypes
    name?: string
}

type Dog = Animal & {
    barkLevel: number
}

type Cat = Animal & {
    jumpHeight: number
}

type Fish = Animal & {
    livingDepth: number
}

type Bear = Animal & {
    climbSpeed: number
}

type Bird = Animal & {
    maxFlightHeight: number
}
```

Now I would like to define an enum to map all the animal-type-names (DOG, CAT, ...) to the TS types of all the specific animals:

```
enum AnimalTypes {
    Dog = "DOG",
    Cat = "CAT",
    Fish = "FISH",
    Bear = "BEAR",
    Bird = "BIRD",
}
```

To loop over an array of Animals (with different types of animals in it) to give each animal a name leads me to the problem, that I don't know how to define the types in the function:

```
const animals: Array<AnimalTypes> = [
    {
        id: "1234",
        type: "DOG",
        barkLevel: 2
    },
    {
        id: "1234",
        type: "CAT",
        jumpHeight: 15
    }    
]

function addName(animals: Array<AnimalTypes>): Array<AnimalTypes> {
    const nameList: Array<string> = ["Puffy", "Lilly", "Birdy"];
    const namedAnimals = [];
    animals.forEach(animal => {
        animal.name = nameList[Math.floor(Math.random()*nameList.length)];
    })
    return namedAnimals;
}
```

This example gives me the following TS-Error:
`Type '{ id: string; type: string; jumpHeight: number; }' is not assignable to type 'AnimalTypes'.(2322)`

Is there a possibility to write an enum (or something else) to map the animal-Types (from "types" field) to the different animal-type-declarations?

Comment: There are quite a few problems with this code and it's hard for me to tell if they are the crux of the question or if they are typos.  First:  you wrote `Array<AnimalTypes>`; is that what you meant? I'd have expected `Array<Animal>`? ... I mean, if I fix the issues I see, I get [this code](https://tsplay.dev/wXgZ8W) but I don't know if that's what you want. How can we proceed here?

Comment: Thank you for your response. What is missing here, is something that defines my type field. Thats what my enum was supposed to be. I want some place to define all my animal-types and map them to a specific ts-type like this: Dog = "DOG". Thats whats missing in your example.

Comment: Then maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7GYPN) is what you're looking for?  If so I could write up an answer about it, but please first [edit] your example code to remove typos, or at least address my first comment where I ask about them... `Array<Animal>` makes sense to me but `Array<AnimalTypes>` does not. Can you either fix it if it's a mistake or explain what it's not a mistake?

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for. Eventhough I didn't really get this line of code: type Animal<K extends keyof AnimalMap = keyof AnimalMap> = { [P in K]: { type: P } & AnimalMap[P] }[K]

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer explaining but please, could you address the points I raised in my previous comments about typos? Right now it seems like you're either missing or ignoring those parts of my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Three corrections should get you moving in the right direction:

- Make Animal an interface (optional?)
- Have each subtype extend from Animal
- Make your array prototype declaration more like

  const animals: Array<Animal>